# getElementsByClassName vs. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If my original function was:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('blah')[9].innerHTML = 'blah';
```

...how would I change that so I get that same item in jquery? I have this, but when I put '[9]' at the end it doesnt work:

```
$(data).find('.blah')[9].html();
```

It I leave the [9] out, it only gets the first item whose class name is 'blah', and I want it to get the 10th item.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The equivalent of

```
document.getElementsByClassName('blah')[9].innerHTML = 'blah';
```

is to use the [`:eq` pseudo-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
$(".blah:eq(9)").html('blah');
```

or the [`eq` function](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(".blah").eq(9).html('blah');
```

(...and then the [`html` function](http://api.jquery.com/html) to set the inner HTML.)

Comment: Prefer the `.eq()` as the `:eq()` pseudo class is non-standard and will thus trigger sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) instead. This is slower than the native `querySelectorAll()` which is used whenever possible

Comment: @rodneyrehm: Yes. In the *extremely* rare cases where it matters. I prefer the function version anyway, truth be told. And yes, there *is* a marginal speed benefit (again, for those extremely rare cases): http://jsperf.com/eq-sel-vs-function

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: +1 and just to add for OPs and future user's benefit why `$(data).find('.blah')[9].html();` didn't work as I didn't see that addressed directly. `@Alex:` When using `[9]` you are getting the HTML element reference not a jQuery wrapped object. Hence you cannot call any jQuery methods on it. That is why you would have to use `.innerHTML` instead: `$(data).find('.blah')[9].innerHtml;`. Which incidentally is very fast as well (about same as `.eq()`) when being pedantic about performance to that level: http://jsperf.com/eq-sel-vs-function/2

Answer (score 2):

See what you are looking for is `:eq()`:

```
$('.blah').eq(9).html('blah');
```

because `:eq()` is `0` indexed,so `:eq(9)` will find the item at 10th index.

[.eq() jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

There is `:nth-child()` function too:

```
$('.blah:nth-child(10)').html('blah');
```

because `:nth-child()` is `1` indexed so you have to give place 10th position there.

[:nth-child() jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

#### from the docs:

> Because jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification, the value of n is "1-indexed", meaning that the counting starts at 1. For other selector expressions such as :eq() or :even jQuery follows JavaScript's "0-indexed" counting. Given a single  containing two
>
> s, $('li:nth-child(1)') selects the first
>
> while $('li:eq(1)') selects the second.

Answer (score 1):

try the following

```
$('.blah').eq(9).html('blah');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.blah').eq(9).html('blah');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also just be able to use jQuery's get() method:

```
$('.blah').get(9)
```

jQuery objects also function as indexed arrays as returned elements, so this should also work:

```
$('.blah')[9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer could be:

```
$($(data).find('.blah')[9]).html();
```

When you use [9] it returns a DOM object which doesn't know what function html() is but without [9] it returns a jQuery Object which the html() function is apart of.

Comment: Using `eq(9)` instead of `[9]` like this: `$(data).find('.blah').eq(9).html()` saves you from having to apply another jQuery wrapper around resulting DOM reference as `eq()` returns a jQuery wrapped object already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".blah:eq(9)").html('blah');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blah')[9].innerHTML="BLAH";
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Use jquery for the selector but not for innerHTML?  Why stop there?

Comment: As far as I understood $('.blah')[9] returns DOM object not a jQuery object so jQuery methods can't be used any longer.