# How to get an element from td array by its class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using this statement:

```
$("td", calendar).getElementsByClassName("today")
```

but I kept getting the error that getElementsByClassName is not a function.

```
$("td", calendar)
```

gives back an array of "td"'s. Is it possible to access the "today" "td" only using one line, or is a some kind of iteration necessary?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("today")` nothing more.

Comment: Post your HTML.

Comment: maybe `$("td", calendar).filter(".today")`

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('td.today')

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719222/getelementsbyclassname-vs-jquery

Comment: What is `calender` here?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay why does it matter?  It's not relevant in the slightest.

Comment: `$("td", calendar).filter(".today")` the same as `$("td.today", calendar)` and the same as `$(calendar).find("td.today")` (and the .filter version), and, depending on what `calendar` is, you could maybe use `calendar.find("td.today")`, but I'd stick with `$("td.today", calendar)` as it saves having to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is a wrapper for DOM elements and has its own helper functions.

To filter a collection of elements, use `.filter` like so:

```
$( 'td', calendar ).filter( '.today' );
```

If you are only going to use `td`s with the `today` class, then it is better to alter your selector:

```
$( 'td.today', calendar );
```

---

You could achieve this with built in JS functions as well, like this

```js
const tdCollection = document.querySelectorAll( 'td.today' );
console.log( tdCollection );
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>yesterday</td>
    <td class="today">today</td>
    <td>tomorrow</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion, and it returned an array, so i just added a [0] and it was fixed, thanks. Do you know which method is faster?

Comment: The last one without jQuery. jQuery itself is just a wrapper which of course relies on built in JS function. I wouldn't recommend using jQuery unless you really need to support older versions of IE - but as far as I know jQuery won't support older versions anyway. Nowadays pretty much everything can be easily done without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing vanilla Javascript with jQuery.

**Javascript**

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("today")
```

this returns all elements with this classname in an array

**jQuery**

```
var x = $('.today');
```

when selecting an element with jquery you need to prepend a "#" for ids and a "." for classes

good luck and have fun learning javascript :)

[EDIT] Sorry, apparently I over read the real problem here. In your specific case you  would best go with a solution similar to what @lumio suggested in his answer.

Comment: I can only imagine this got downvoted (not be me) because it didn't answer the specific case in the question.  Maybe add a line and, "in your case, this means use..."